# Multiple Insert PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried loads of examples on StackOverflow as well as some found on Google, but none helps me.

I have a form on my website which I use to add products into my database. It was a bit too slow so I made a form with multiple forms so I can add upto 8 items at once. My problem is, I cannot get the process form to add all of them at once. I should also add that my script checks if a checkbox was ticked or not, and if ticked, it adds it using this :

```
if(isset($_POST['p1set'])) { 'check if checkbox is checked and continue
    $pname = $_POST['p1name'];
    $description = $_POST["p1descript"];
    $finishes = $_POST['p1colors'];
    $price = $_POST['p1price'];
    $manufacturer = $_POST['p1manu'];
    $category = $_GET['cat'];
    if(!empty($_FILES['p1image'] ['name'])) {
    $target = "images/";
    $target = $target.basename($_FILES['p1image'] ['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['p1image'] ['tmp_name'], $target);
    $pic = $_FILES['p1image'] ['name'];
    $outFile = "images/thm_".$pic;
    $image = new Imagick("../product/images/".$pic);
    $image->thumbnailImage(84, 0);
    $image->writeImage($outFile);
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products(ID, name, description, finishes, price, manufacturer, image, category, thumb) VALUES (NULL, '$pname', '$description', '$finishes', '$price', '$manufacturer', '$pic', '$category', '$outFile')";
   mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   mysqli_close($con);
   }
```

This works fine, but only for one product. I just want it to process all the items that have been ticked, add them to the database and when all the queries have completed, display a javascript alert.

Any ideas on this??

Comment: what comes in $_POST['p1set']?

Comment: @Khushboo : $_POST['p1set'] is the checkbox. That checks if it is ticked or not

Comment: you should give checkbox name as array and use foreach loop to insert data

Comment: @Khushboo : I have tried that, but have no idea whatsoever how to use it. I lost the example I had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array in "name" like below:-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Daily">Daily
```

Then use for loop :-

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST['Days']); $i++){
// Do Code Here
}
```

Comment: where is the condition for checking is checkbox is true or not ? as per OP need ?

Comment: only the checked checkbox value will come in the array

Comment: @Khushboo : Do you have an example of how to store the text of 3 textboxes into an array and the retrieve it using a foreach loop?

Comment: same as checkbox. Give "name" as array for textboxes like txt[]

Comment: @Khushboo : Thanks a lot. Oh, just one last thing, how can I seperate the values of the 3 boxes inside the array. I tried using 'name="txt[name]" and name="txt[email]"' but no luck.

Comment: you will get array like 

[txt] => Array
        (
            ['name'] => 1
            ['email'] => foo
        )